# Image handler for image request fails in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, httprequest

we have uploaded our images into the CDN and from there we are requesting images. My question is, i need to write an image handler that check the requested image is available or not in CDN, and the request failed because of image not found or some other error like CDN down, i have to redirect that image request to local image location. How can i do this?

For example, If the request for image,

"http://cdn.images.net/content/images/image1.png" this request fails, then i should redirect that request to "http://www.example.com/content/images/images1.png".

How can i handle this using image handler?

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTTP HEAD request for this purpose. By doing so you will only get HTTP headers as response. Here is a simple example:

```
public bool ImageExists(string imageUri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(imageUri);
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return true;
        else
            return false;  
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

...and here is how it's called:

```
if (ImageExists(firstUri) 
{
    // Download from http://cdn.images.net...
}
else
{
    // Download from http://www.example.com...
}
```

There may also be useful to check if the mime-type of the response is *image/png*, depending on how your request is handled at the remote server.